# Quitar cifras en conversión de decimal a binario en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente programa que pasa un número a binario.

```py
#34. Plantee e implemente un programa para convertir un número entero a binario. 
if __name__=="__main__":
    n=int(input("Introduce el entero positivo que quieras a binario: "))
    cociente=None
    resto=0
    while cociente !=0:
        resto=str(resto)+str((n%2)) #Concatenamos los restos, ya que es el numero en binario
        #Tenemos que convertir los restos a str ya que si no, al ser números, se suman.
        cociente=n//2 #Evaluamos el conciente hasta que sea 0 porque es la condición del bucle
        n=n//2 #Actualizamos el valor de n para volver a hacer la división nuevamente
    print (f'{resto}')
```

El problema es que siempre me genera un `0` al principio porque tengo declarado `resto=0` al principio del código. ¿Hay alguna función de python que permita visualizar un número a partir de la segunda posición?

```
Introduce el entero positivo que quieras a binario: 25
010011
```

Comment: Podes usar slices (resto[1:]). Igual, ten en cuenta que los slices no funcionan con enteros, asi tendras que convertirlo en cadena primero. Sin embargo, diria que tu mejor opción en realidad es setear resto en una cadena vacia. Es lo que hago habitualmente cuando estoy concatenando cadenas con un bucle for. Eso hara que en la primera iteracion ocurra una concatenacion entre una cadena vacia y resto, que resultará en lo mismo que resto sin concatenar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas:
(1) Estás inicializando un acumulador tipo cadena en `0`, obviamente `str(0)` será `'0'` por lo que ese valor será incluído en la cadena.
(2) En la conversión binaria, el primer valor obtenido será el último y viceversa. Para corregirlo solo hay que invertir el orden de esta operación: `str(resto) + str((n%2))`

Con esas correcciones, el código quedará:

```py
if __name__=="__main__":
    n = int(input("Introduce el entero positivo que quieras a binario: "))
    cociente = None
    resto = ''
    while cociente != 0:
        resto = str(n%2) + resto # Concatenamos los restos, ya que es el numero en binario
        cociente = n // 2 # Evaluamos el cociente hasta ser 0, porque es la condición del bucle
        n = cociente # Actualizamos el valor de n para hacer la división nuevamente
    print (f'{resto}')
```

Prueba:

```
Introduce el entero positivo que quieras a binario: 157
10011101
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por la corrección